# how can I call view method in different files

Tags: python, django

If I have one view which called myview1.py and I want to call a view which is located in myview2.py, how can I do that?

should I import myview2.py somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to read about [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), but here's the cheat sheet:

```
$ cat gilliam.py
def spam():
    print 'eggs'
$ cat jones.py
import gilliam
gilliam.spam()
$ python jones.py
eggs
```

Answer (score 3):

just `import` it

```
from myview2 import viewname1, viewname2

value = viewname1(params)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just do

```
import myview2
```

and be able to access it's methods from there, assuming myview2.py is in your include path.

Comment: from helpdesk.views.myview2 import * 

? 

or what do you mean I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo; what I meant to type import myview2 (or rather import helpdesk.views.myview2). Then you can access all functionality through the imported module

e.g.

    x = myview2.someClass()